# how to fix that my method returns nothing for the second index?

Tags: php, arrays, debugging

I already asked this but I dont know how to fix it please help, my $obj->obtainID($a); i returns nothing for the second index.

Description:
I got an $arrayDirectoy variable which contains just 2 values, then I tried to pass that variable to a query in a for loop to retrieve the ids of each one, but It just echo me one id, and there are two ids, I dont know how to fix that, It just print me 1 id.

Example $arrayDirectory[] = {user1, user2};

it must echo 1 2 but just print me 1

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arrayDirectory);$i++){ 
    $res[$i] = $obj->obtainID($arrayDirectory[$i]);

    echo $res[$i];

}
```

this is my obtainID method

```
public function obtainID($user){

        $conexion = $this->objConexion->configuracion();
        $query = "CALL sp_xxx('$user')";
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultado = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        return $res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues. First, you have a syntax error -- you forgot a closing parenthesis to sizeof():

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arrayDirectory;$i++){
```

Also, if you're not changing the number of elements, there's no need to call `sizeof()` more than once:

```
$count = count($arrayDirectory); // or sizeof(), doesn't matter
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
```

Lastly, you should be calling `count()` or `sizeof()` on `$arrayDirectory[0]`, **not** `$arrayDirectory`. This is because the array only has one element, which happens to be an object that contains two fields. Alternatively, it probably makes sense for `$arrayDirectory` to just be an object, not an array.

So, your final code should look like:

```
$arrayDirectory = {'user1', 'user2'};
$count = count($arrayDirectory); // or sizeof(), doesn't matter
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) 
    $res[$i] = $obj->obtainID($arrayDirectory[$i]);
    echo $res[$i];
}
```

Comment: yes I make those changes but I think the problem its with obtainId method because it does not retunr nothing for the index 1 and so on but for index 0 it return and id

Comment: It not executing the other querys

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking for errors. Try checking for

```
if (!$stmt->execute()) { print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); }
```

also, I wouldn't use `fetchColumn()` I'd use either `fetch()` or `fetchAll()` if you have more than one result.

Comment: ho do you use fetch or fetchall in in my case? It returns array but fetchcolum no

Comment: It is not executing the other querys it throws an error when I equals to true